# Changing a Tuple element (sequence) to sequence length (int)

Tags: arrays, string, f#, tuples

I have this noob problem that im trying to fix but I cant

I have an array of tuples in the form of

```
tuple: (string*(string*seq<string>)[])[]
```

I wish to convert the "seq" to the sequence length (int)

I tried in various forms with

```
Seq.length
```

but I haven't been able to do it, can anyone help?
thanks!

Comment: If you're *only* creating the sequences so you can count their elements, and if you're doing that using `Seq.groupBy`, then you should use `Seq.countBy` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array.map (fun (s,e) -> s, Array.map (fun (s,e) -> s, Seq.length e) e) tupArray
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will map the nested sequence to its length:

```
let map arg : (string*(string*int)[])[] =
    arg |> Array.map (fun (s1, arr) ->
        s1, arr |> Array.map (fun (s2, coll) -> s2, Seq.length coll))
```

But seeing how complex the type you have there is, I wonder do you represent with it? You'd almost certainly want to use something more palatable then this.